# How to get collapsible & expandable list for android without using jquery 1.0.1.css

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to get something like as shown in below[image]

and the code i used for it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>Tasks Today</h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                        <li data-theme="c">
                            <a href="#" data-transition="slide">
                                list1
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-theme="c">
                            <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                                list2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li data-theme="c">
                            <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                                list3
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>


           <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                    <h3>
                        Tasts This Week
                    </h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                     <li data-theme="c">
                            <a href="#" data-transition="slide">
                                Button
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

</body>
</html>
```

But i don't want to use the below css in my code as it is effecting my existing UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
```

Can anyone help me in getting same output as i shown with out using this jquery css?

I replaced my css with structure css and i'm getting the UI as shown
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle. In basically includes the collapsible, listview and theme css from git repository https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/css

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/UCDfU/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery.mobile.structure.css which just gives you the functional CSS without all the styling.

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.css

This is version 1.1.0 which is the latest. You can use this if you are updating to 1.1.0 or use the one for your version.

Looks like you want the style as well as the structure. The only option then is to change the CSS. If there are too many conflicts with your UI and the only thing you want is the list, copy the CSS from the JQM CSS theme file http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.theme-1.1.0.css in to your own CSS.

Look for all the CSS with `.ui-collapsible` to get the styles for the collapsible element. The best way to find the CSS classes for elements is to use the Web Developer/Firebug tools in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Did you try the structure CSS?

Comment: hi i replaced my css with the structure css and i'm getting the result as shown in pic of my above question. There i'm able to get the collapse functionality but not able to get the UI as shown in my first pic. can u help me in this? @codemonkey

Comment: thank u for ur response is it possible to tell me which part of css will work for the collapse button view along with + and - symbol when expand and collapse i'm not good in css so not able to find. I have my own css for listview inside collapse button so i need only styling for activites today button in my pic can u help me in this?